# Regex - Is the way I'm extracting text from a string the most concise?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use Regex to extract text from a string ignoring case. Below is how I did it? Am I missing any caveats?

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string result = Regex.Match(@"inVentoryPassword1234.Txt", @"(?i)(?<=Inventory).*(?=.txt)(?-i)").Value;
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/g4cU6D/1/

Comment: What part of the `inVentoryPassword1234.Txt` string do you want to extract?

Comment: Anything between inventory and .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error. The `.` before `txt` should be escaped, otherwise it matches any character.

```
(?i)(?<=Inventory).*(?=\.txt)
```

Also, it would be safer to test for success:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(@"inVentoryPassword1234.Txt", @"(?i)(?<=Inventory).*(?=\.txt)");
if (match.Success) {
    string result = match.Value;
    Console.Write(result);
}
```

The flags are effective for the remainder of the pattern. But since there is no remainder, you can drop `(?-i)`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [named groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#grouping-constructs) for extracting text. They are more readable in my opinion. Here is an example:

```
var source = @"inVentoryPassword1234.Txt";
var pattern = @"Inventory(?<Result>.*?)\.txt";
var match = Regex.Match(source, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(match.Success ? match.Groups["Result"].Value : "Not found");
```

The `(?<Result>.*?)` is a named group with the arbitrary name "Result", that matches anything [as few times as possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#quantifiers) (non-greedy).